# MacBook Air 2020 multiport not working properly

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, charging

**The problem:** One of the USB-C port of my multiport is not wokring, all others are working fine.

**In detail:**
The multiport has two USBC sockets, SD and micro-SD card reader and 2 "normal" USB (I think version 3.0) sockets. One of the USB-C ports does not work, but all other sockets do. I need at least one USB-C for an external display and the other to charge the MacBook Air from time to time, but since I cannot use both I need to disconnect the display to charge the notebook.

**What I've tried:**
The display and charging works fine on the one USB-C socket and also no problems if connected directly (I need the multiport also for the USB ports, that's why I still need it...)
The multiport should be working fine as I tried another one (same type) because the first did not work.

Is there any updates to do or driver problems I have to solve? I am not so experienced in this kind of field.

[image: Only the USB-C port on the far left works]

Comment: You write "The multiport should be working fine as I tried another one (same type) because the first did not work." This is unclear: _which_ multiport should work? Did the second multiport work correctly?

Comment: What I meant by that is, that it is unlikely that it is a problem from the mutliport, as I tried not only one (If I tried only one we could also assume that it is defect). So in fact, I don't know if it works fine, but I assume that that multiport type works normally.

Comment: This is still not clear. Do both multiports behave the same?

Comment: Sorry, maybe its my English... Yes both behave the same way. Both are new.

Comment: No worries, you're doing much better in English than I could in Portuguese. With this clearer information, I've now submitted an Answer.

Answer (score 1):

If both multiports behave the same way — that is, show the same flaw —  then it's likely the flaw is with the multiports' design or construction, or both, and not the fault of the Mac.